# append option to multiple select boxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select

I wanted to add an option to multiple select boxes but some how I am not able to do this, below is my code snippet. please help me to solve this problem.

```
<select name="selBx-1" id="selBx-1" class="sel-opt">
    <option value="general">General</option>
    <option value="special">Special</option>
    <option value="addnew">Add New</option>
</select> 

<select name="selBx-2" id="selBx-2" class="sel-opt">
    <option value="general">General</option>
    <option value="special">Special</option>
    <option value="addnew">Add New</option>
</select> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(document).on("change",".sel-opt",function(){
        var selVal = $(this).val();
        if(selVal == 'addnew')
        {
            $(".sel-opt option:last").before("<option value='newoption'>New Option</option>");
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell if this is the exact functionality you're looking for, but hope it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $(".sel-opt").on("change", function(){
        if($(this).val() === "addnew"){
            $(".sel-opt").find("option:last").before("<option value='newoption'>New Option</option>");
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('select').change(function(){
        var selVal = $(this).val();
        if(selVal == 'addnew')
        {
            $(".sel-opt").each(function() {
                $(this).children('option').filter(':last').before(new Option("New Option", "newoption"));
            });
        }
    })
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/whdofa4v/)